# Connect with existing MySQL database (OVH) from Cloud Functions

Tags: mysql, firebase, function, google-cloud-firestore, cloud

I have an existing database hosted by OVH and managed by PhpMyAdmin.
On the other side, I also have a Firebase project where I use several Cloud Functions.

I would like write, in my existing OVH database, datas from my Firestore collections (thanks to Cloud Functions).

Is there a way to connect my Cloud Functions to an existing database ?

I did read than is possible to connect Cloud Functions to MySQL database with Cloud SQL but it seems only for new database created from Cloud Platform, which is not my usecase as my database is already created and hosted by OVH.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the programming language you are using on Cloud Functions, PHP for example:

```
 1. <?php
 2. $myPDO = new PDO('pgsql:host=host;port=port;dbname=dbname', 'username', 'password');
 3. ?>
```

From what I can tell on the documents, you have to make sure your database is public, not private. Here is the [official documentation](https://docs.ovh.com/gb/en/hosting/connecting-to-database-on-database-server/).

If you have any issues, try reaching out to [OVH support](https://help.ovhcloud.com/en-gb/).

Comment: Hi Oliver, thank you for the reply. In Cloud Functions, the language is TypeScript, kind of JavaScript. I found this docs https://fireship.io/lessons/sql-firebase-typeorm/#connection-options where they configure connection for Cloud MySQL (Google database) and they say that is "specifically for Google Cloud SQL."
I don't think that I can use PHP script in this type script.
I'll ask to OVH support.
Ih you have an idea, let me know ! Thanks again.